# python pyc only modules results in ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, import, module, pyc

i have a folder 'module' with only .pyc files (and a **init**.pyc too)

```
module/
  __init__.pyc
  one.pyc
  two.pyc

test.py
```

`test.py` contains the import lines:

```
import module.one 
import module.two
```

or

```
from module import one
from module import two
```

will both fail.
only

```
import module
```

works but gives not access to the files `one` and `two`

any hints?

.F

Comment: Where did the .pyc files come from?  You need to be sure they were made with the same version of Python.  Also, if you start Python with -v or -vv, it will show information as it tries to import things.

Comment: Could not reproduce. For example, try the series of commands (on UNIX) `mkdir module; touch module/__init__.py; touch module/one.py; python -c "from module import one"; rm module/*.py; python -c "from module import one"; python -c "import module.one"`- no errors for me.

Comment: Are you sure that the `no module named` error is `no module named one`, and not an ImportError thrown by `one.py` or `two.py` themselves?

Comment: Maybe what you called `module` is actually a name already existing, and thus the import fetches the other package/module which, obviously, does not have a `one` or `two` submodules? Try to open an interactive interpreter and type `help('modules')`. If you find the name of your module there, then this might be the problem.

Comment: the problem seems related to pypy, not python.
i types in all lines above using python and that worked as expected.
Trying the same using pypy failed with the message ImportError: No module named module

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can import ".pyc" files. You need to put ".py" files in the module folder.